# Problem with a delegate function returning a nullable value

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following code:

```
private T? FromCache<T>(CacheKey key, Func<T?> retriever)
{
    if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out T res))
        return res;
    res = retriever();
    if (res is not null)
        cache.Set(key, res);
    return res;
}

public decimal? GetClosingExchangeRate(string sourceCurrencyCode, string targetCurrencyCode)
{
    return FromCache<decimal>(CacheKey.Closing(sourceCurrencyCode, targetCurrencyCode),
            // The following line results in this error:
            // Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
            () => GetExchangeRate(sourceCurrencyCode, targetCurrencyCode)?.ClosingRate
        );
}
public ExchangeRateDefinition? GetExchangeRate(string sourceCurrencyCode, string targetCurrencyCode)
{
    return GetExchangeRateQuery(sourceCurrencyCode, targetCurrencyCode).FirstOrDefault();
}
public class ExchangeRateDefinition
{
    [...]
    public decimal? ClosingRate { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

In this case,

I do not understand the error: as far as I understand, the delegate passed to the FromCache method has a return type of `T?` which should translate to `decimal?` which is exactly when the delegate I use returns. Yet, the error message seems to indicates the compiler is expecting a delegate that returns a non-nullable decimal instead.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: `return FromCache<decima?>` maybe.. Anyway this is far from a reproducible example, I paste your code and most of it is errors

Comment: Your question does not appear to have anything specific with respect to version 9 of C#. I've removed that tag, as it was inappropriate. If you feel your question is _specific to_ C# 9, you need to edit the post to make clear why. And FWIW, I concur with the previous comment that the question is inadequate, as it lacks a proper [mcve]. See also [ask] for more information on how to present the question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a reproducible example from your code:

```
internal class NullableExample
{
    private T? FromCache<T>(System.Func<T?> retriever)
    {
        return retriever();
    }

    public decimal? GetClosingExchangeRate()
    {
        return FromCache<decimal>(
                // The following line results in this error:
                // Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
                () => default(decimal?)
            );
    }
}
```

---

The problem is in your call to `FromCache<decimal>`:

The type argument you're specifying is `decimal` but

```
GetExchangeRate(sourceCurrencyCode, targetCurrencyCode)?.ClosingRate
```

(which I simplified to `default(decimal?)`) returns a `decimal?`.

You need to change

```
FromCache<decimal>
```

to

```
FromCache<decimal?>
```

or you could just elide the type argument and have

```
return FromCache(
        // The following line results in this error:
        // Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        () => default(decimal?)
    );
```

so the compiler can figure out that you're calling `FromCache<decimal?>`.

---

The underlying issue is that you're using the [nullable reference type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/) syntax but [`Decimal` is a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal) so when passing ` to

```
private T? FromCache<T>(System.Func<T?> retriever)
```

the compiler sees

```
private decimal FromCache<decimal>(System.Func<decimal> retriever)
```

instead of

```
private decimal? FromCache<decimal>(System.Func<decimal?> retriever)
```

as you are expecting.

You can see this (in Visual Studio) by seeing what the Intellisense says:

> [image]

The same issue occurs if you make `FromCache` work with `T` instead of `T` and `T?` (i.e. get rid of the nullable reference type syntax):

```
internal class NullableExample
{
    private T FromCache<T>(System.Func<T> retriever)
    {
        return retriever();
    }

    public decimal? GetClosingExchangeRate()
    {
        return FromCache<decimal>(
                // The following line results in this error:
                // Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
                () => default(decimal?)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it: from cache is defined as `private T? FromCache<T>? which should mean that `FromCache<decimal>` returns a `decimal?`

Comment: I've edited my answer - the problem is that you're using the nullable reference type syntax but Decimal is a struct.